# Number of lines of codes Vs Number of files; Which one increase the app size?

Tags: ios, mvvm

In my new project, I moved to MVVM architecture. Earlier while using MVC, I was dumping all the codes in the viewController file which makes it hard to understand and cluttered. Using MVVM architecture, I now can provide a balanced distribution of codes among different files. So instead of one model and viewController class for a particular screen, I now have a model, a viewController and a viewModel(where I moved some of the codes from viewController). I also sometimes use separate files for storing all the IBOutlets, if too many IBOutlets are there for a viewController. Also I sometimes move the tableView/collectionView delegate and dataSource methods to another file.

So when I started to give importance to code structure and good standards, the number of files in the project got increased. MVVM architecture is good for developers in terms of understanding the code, testing purposes, and flexibility. But my question is, will it be good for the end users? Will it increase the app size if we use more files? Will it affect the performance, because instead of referring one file for all the functionalities related to a screen, the system now has to check different files?

Comment: Definitely lines of code. Your code will get compiled to a single binary file.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App size depends on 3 things:

1. How many commands are there in your project (not line, not file)
2. Size of resource in your project (image, data, sound, video, text file...)
3. Build profile (debug or release), debug model will get bigger size

Answer (score 1):

It does not affect the app size or performance.

> **Simple Example**

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) print("hello"); /* How many lines of code is this? */
```

compare this code with

```
/* Now how many lines of code is this? */
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    print("hello");
}
```

according to you which one is faster. or increase app size.

**Conclusion**
From above code it will defiantly  increase your source code size **But not app size** 
Because swift complier will create single binary file from all the source files (So clearly it doesn't matter at all ).

Comment: Your example isn't appropriate to this question at all. Removing white space versus refactoring code into different classes and extensions are not at all the same.

Comment: @rmaddy the conclusion is  Your code will get compiled to a single binary file. (no separate file is included)

Comment: Thanks @JaydeepVyas, it gave more clarification and perspective to my quest. Upvoting for that. But not marking as the correct answer as for now. I am hoping for some more answers and discussions to come.

Comment: Depending on how the OP refactored their code, the app may actually be slightly larger because there may be more classes and more code getting all of those classes working together. I think the OP is worrying about a non-issue but your example is not the same thing. The OP did a lot more than simply split X lines of code in Y files to X lines of code in Z files. The OP probably split X lines of code into 1.1X lines of code. But it's not just the count of lines. It's the number of classes and the complexity of their interactions.

Comment: i think if you check the source folder Then B is large but the .ipa does't . affect

Comment: Suppose I have 2 projects A and B, both contains same code in X number of lines. In A, I distributed that code in 3 classes. In B, I distributed that in 6 classes. But number of lines remains X in both. So which one will have more app size? A or B?

Comment: i mean to say that it will not affect after creating build.